# Enemies always clumping together in unity 2d

Tags: visual-studio

I'm trying to make a top-down shooter game in unity 2d. But the enemies are always clumping together. Does someone knows how to avoid it?
Here's my enemy code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour
{
public float moveSpeed;
public float stoppingDistance;
public Transform player;
private Rigidbody2D rb;
public GameObject effect;
public int health = 3;
public static int enemyCounter;
public SpriteRenderer enemy;
public Color hurtColor;



void Start() {
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform;
}

void Update() {
    enemyCounter = EnemySpawner.enemyCounter;
    Vector2 direction = transform.position - player.position;
    if (Vector2.Distance(transform.position, player.position) > stoppingDistance) {
        transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, player.position, 
moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
    else if (Vector2.Distance(transform.position, player.position) > stoppingDistance) {
        transform.position = this.transform.position;
    }

}

IEnumerator Flash(){
    enemy.color = hurtColor;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.01f);
    enemy.color = Color.red;
}
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other) {
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Bullet") {
        StartCoroutine(Flash());
        health -= 1;
    }
    if (health <= 0) {
        GameObject DestroyEnemy = Instantiate(effect, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
        Destroy(DestroyEnemy, 2f);
    }

}



}
```

The enemies is moving towards the player, but they clump together when I move the player. I really need help.

Answer (score 0):

If the enemies are moving in straight line to the player they will always clump up. If you want to ensure a minimal distance between enemies you could consider using a second larger collider on another layer but this will might end up looking bad and could make some exploits possible if too big.

The other alternative would be to change the behaviour of the enemies. Making an enemy move depending on the position of the other enemies seems complicated therefore i would simply try to add some randomness to their behaviour. Here are some ideas you could try:

-(would be my first try) switch randomly between two behaviours, 1: move straight to the player (always if very close to player), 2: move in a random direction (sometimes when further away from the player)

-don't give all your enemies the same speed

-make them move towards the player + a small random angle away from the player if far away

-...

To sum it up you will need an improved behaviour and there isn't a single solution.

Comment: Yeah, I will try, but I heard people putting some kind of force to avoid clumping together.

Comment: This can be used to create easy forcefields https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PointEffector2D.html. It will look better than using a simple collider, but they will still group, they will just be further away from each other. you could also try to code this yourself, use a trigger collider, and add a small movement component, to both enemies, away from each other when it is triggered